# extjs: get ref for button created with form.buttons?

Tags: extjs

After creating buttons on a form with buttons: [{ }], which is meant to be shorthand for the whole docked item syntax, inspection shows that form.buttons is null, and the buttons only exist in form.dockedItems. Since .buttons is a Config, shouldn't they be able to be accessed that way? Would be a little easier than diving into docked items or am I being picky? :-) tia

Answer (score 1):

You can use the down() selector to grab it:

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {

    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        buttons: [{
            itemId: 'b1',
            text: 'Foo'
        }]
    });

    console.log(panel.down('#b1'));

});
```

Comment: k with you on this ... I am inside a controller where I have "var form1 = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('FmTabWiz1');"